# Read HttpRuntime.Cache item as read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, httpruntime.cache

I am using a `HttpRuntime.Cache` to store a list of objects that will be accessing frequently across sessions.

I use the following line of code to get the item from the cache:

```
List<chartData_Type> _chartData = 
             (List<chartData_Type>)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("rollingMonth");
```

But, unfortunately when I update the **_chartData**, it updates the cached item too.

How can I simply get a copy of the cached item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the way which .NET works because Cache just reference to the *pointer* of `List`. Don't know whether you `chartData_Type` is value type or reference type.

If value type, it is easy to use:

```
List<chartData_Type> list = new List<chartData_Type>(_chartData);
```

But if reference type, it comes to complicated, you need to implement *[DeepCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23832/Implementing-Deep-Cloning-via-Serializing-objects#xx3984032xx)* method for your class, then do `DeepCopy` for each object in list.

`DeepClone` method:

```
public static class CloneHelper
{
    public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use this method, class `chartData_Type` must be marked `[Serializable]`:

```
[Serializable]
class chartData_Type
{}
```

So, you can do deep clone manually:

```
var cloneChartData = _chartData.Select(d => 
                                       CloneHelper.DeepClone<chartData_Type>(d))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: I am wondering whether AppFabric or NCache would solve this problem.  I asked this in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546817/appfabric-ncache-will-these-solve-httpruntime-cache-objects-being-updated-by-r

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
List<chartData_Type> list = new List<chartData_Type>(_chartData);
```

It will copy all items from `_chartData` to `list`.

Comment: Note that this will be a deep copy of the object so you will have to make sure that the cache and this copy remain in synch otherwise ... OOOOOPS!

Comment: Maybe a little explanation as to why his copy is updating the cache version as well. Will get my up vote =P

Answer (score 1):

List is a reference type and _chartData holds the address of the original object stored in the cache. That is why when you update _chartData, it updates the cached object too. If you want a separate object then clone the cached object. See below reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33364/ASP-NET-Runtime-Cache-Clone-Objects-to-Preserve-Ca

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45168/ASP-NET-Runtime-Cache-Clone-Objects-to-Preserve-Ca