# Create copy of List<t> without reference to original

Tags: c#, reference

I know this has been covered before but from what I understand in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447248/c-sharp-how-to-assign-listt-without-being-a-reference%20this) this should work.

**Example code:**

I have a custom type:

```
public class MyType
{
    public List<MySubType> Movie { get; set; }
    public List<int> Ranks { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Released { get; set; }
}
```

I then create a List of this type

```
List<MyType> myMovies = new List<MyType>();
```

Later in the code I need to create a copy of this list and change it without affecting the original.

```
List<MyType> copyMovies = new List<MyType>(myMovies);
```

But now if I remove from the list within copyMovies

```
copyMovies.Movie.RemoveAt(x);
```

It removes from both lists

Unless I am totally missing something [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447248/c-sharp-how-to-assign-listt-without-being-a-reference%20this) post suggests I should be able to change the copy list without it effecting the original.

Comment: Have you tried to clone the list? like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: That's not true. If you remove from the second it will not be removed from the first.

Comment: Your code should work. `new List<MyType>(myMovies)` should create a new list containing the same items. Your problem seems to be external to the question.

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: Are u sure ? You really tested the RemoveAt?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe it shouldn't but it is.

Comment: If so, I believe at some stage you do this `copyMovies = myMovies;`

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Yes many times

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No nowhere in the code do I do that.

Comment: So you're saying that one list's `RemoveAt()` method is deleting items of another list? That is physically impossible unless both lists are referencing the same list object.

Comment: Nope, If you need more help you need to provide a short but complete sample which reproduces the problem!

Comment: @Tarec I have just checked, rechecked and triple rechecked the code and that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Fred I've tested your implementation, and it works fine. Please, execute your test again.

Comment: And the downvote was for what exactly?  Or the close vote come to that!!

Comment: @Fred The downvote is because your implementation works fine, you didn't validate correctly before open a question.

Comment: @Fred For writing nonsense. The code you provided IS NOT generating the problem you're describing. You refuse to show us the rest of your code, thus your questions is pointless.

Comment: @Tarec Ok slightly misleading.  I am removing from the List within the List (question updated). But it IS generating the problem I explain.

Comment: @Fred: See my updated answer. Your example was wrong.

Comment: @Fred: now your code wouldn't even compile because a `List<T>` has no `Movie` property. Maybe something like `copyMovies[0].Movie.RemoveAt` but then you should show your real code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point well made.  Bit of a moot point now but the original code... `surveyCollectionToUpload[s].Surveys.RemoveAt(i);` I just missed a vital bit out of my question probably due to tiredness. I am now doing a deep clone using DataContractSerializer. I think the firing squad will be round for me at 8!

Answer (score 17):

You can simply call `ToList()` on your original list, and it will generate a copy.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure your code should work. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says about the constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class **that contains elements copied** from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.

Are you sure you didn't miss anything?

**EDIT:**

You did miss something... Your example was wrong and misleading. Your edit showed you try to delete an item from the list INSIDE your type. These are not copied / cloned when copying the parent class. You need to Clone each and every single property of your class. Take a look at [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Yes I did miss something and I apologize unreservedly to the SO community for the obvious destress caused.  Thanks for your link.

Comment: @Fred: No problem. Usually people know here where they are talking about, so don't keep saying it doesn't work and you tested it, while it doesn't. But in the end, we have all been there.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you think that `copyMovies.RemoveAt(x)` instead of `copyMovies.Movie.RemoveAt(x)` is only SLIGHTLY MISLEADING then sorry my friend, but you're just wasting our time here.

Internal list has been copied by a reference, so you need to copy the whole internal list instead, f.e:

```
List<MyType> copyMovies = new List<MyType>(myMovies.Select (m => new MyType()
{
    Movie = new List<MySubType>(m.Movie),
    Ranks = m.Ranks,
    Location = m.Location,
    Released = m.Released
}));
```

or

```
List<MyType> copyMovies = myMovies.Select (m => new MyType()
{
    Movie = new List<MySubType>(m.Movie),
    Ranks = m.Ranks,
    Location = m.Location,
    Released = m.Released
}).ToList();
```

Or with the copy constructor:

```
//in MyType definition
public MyType(MyType objectToCopy)
{
    Movie = new List<MySubType>(m.Movie);
    Ranks = m.Ranks;
    Location = m.Location;
    Released = m.Released;
}
```

and then you'd be able to use it this way:

```
List<MyType> copyMovies = myMovies.Select (m => new MyType(m));
```

Comment: 28 hrs straight and I missed a bit of detail that, even now I understand to be the problem, still cannot see why a cloning the object would only clone part of it. Shoot me now why dont you!

Comment: @Fred: That is called: by design. What do you think happens when cloning objects with multiple, maybe even circular, references? How to determine what to clone and what not?

Comment: @Fred No, whole list has been cloned. You need to realize the list does not hold reference-type objects, it only holds REFERENCES to them. ALL references has been cloned properly, they just have been pointing to the same `MyType` objects.